# Pygame Collision Bug

Tags: collision-detection, python, pygame

I'm trying to add collisions to my first game, and it has a bug.

My code is:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import sys
import os
import time
width = 950
height = 500

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
Game = False
pygame.init()
icon = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Images", "icon.png")).convert_alpha()
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)
pygame.display.set_caption('Flappy Dog')

def game():
    Game = True
    background = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Images", "Background_00.png")).convert()
    Dog1 = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Images", "Dog1.png")).convert_alpha()
    SpikeUp0 = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Images", "SpikeUp0.png")).convert_alpha()
    SpikeDown0 = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Images", "SpikeDown0.png")).convert_alpha()
    Bone = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Images", "Bone.png")).convert_alpha()

    boneSprite = pygame.sprite.Sprite()
    boneSprite.image = Bone
    boneSprite.rect = boneSprite.image.get_rect()
    spikeUpSprite = pygame.sprite.Sprite()
    spikeUpSprite.image = SpikeUp0
    spikeUpSprite.rect = spikeUpSprite.image.get_rect()
    spikeDownSprite = pygame.sprite.Sprite()
    spikeDownSprite.image = SpikeDown0
    spikeDownSprite.rect = spikeDownSprite.image.get_rect()
    dogSprite = pygame.sprite.Sprite()
    dogSprite.image = Dog1
    dogSprite.rect = dogSprite.image.get_rect()
    bones = pygame.sprite.Group()
    bones.add(boneSprite)
    dog = pygame.sprite.Group()
    dog.add(dogSprite)
    spikes = pygame.sprite.Group()
    spikes.add(spikeUpSprite)
    spikes.add(spikeDownSprite)
    pygame.display.update()

    Dog1_pos_y = 100
    Dog1_pos_x = 30

    while Game == True:
        pygame.event.pump()
        if pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_UP]: # Up
            Dog1_pos_y -= 1
            screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
            screen.blit(Dog1, (Dog1_pos_x, Dog1_pos_y))
            screen.blit(SpikeDown0, (0, 436))
            screen.blit(SpikeUp0, (0, 0))
            pygame.display.update()
            pygame.time.delay(1)
        else: # Down
            Dog1_pos_y = Dog1_pos_y +0.875
            screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
            screen.blit(Dog1, (Dog1_pos_x, Dog1_pos_y))
            screen.blit(SpikeDown0, (0, 436))
            screen.blit(SpikeUp0, (0, 0))
            pygame.display.update()
            pygame.time.delay(1)
        if pygame.key.get_pressed() [K_LEFT]:
            Dog1_pos_x -= 1.5
            screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
            screen.blit(Dog1, (Dog1_pos_x, Dog1_pos_y))
            screen.blit(SpikeDown0, (0, 436))
            screen.blit(SpikeUp0, (0, 0))
            pygame.display.update()
            pygame.time.delay(1)
        if pygame.key.get_pressed() [K_RIGHT]:
            Dog1_pos_x += 1.5
            screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
            screen.blit(Dog1, (Dog1_pos_x, Dog1_pos_y))
            screen.blit(SpikeDown0, (0, 436))
            screen.blit(SpikeUp0, (0, 0))
            pygame.display.update()
            pygame.time.delay(1)

        if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(dogSprite, spikes):
            print ("GAME OVER")
        for event in pygame.event.get():
             if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                 pygame.quit()
                 sys.exit()
                 pygame.display.update()


def gameOver():
    background = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Images", "Background_00.png")).convert()
    GameOver = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Images", "Game-Over.png")).convert_alpha()
    replay = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Images", "Replay.png")).convert_alpha()
    Dog0 = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Images", "Dog0.png")).convert_alpha()
    Bone = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Images", "Bone.png")).convert_alpha()


    screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
    screen.blit(GameOver, (0, 0))
    screen.blit(replay, (600, 375))
    screen.blit(Dog0, (10, 250))
    pygame.display.flip()

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
                pygame.display.update()
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                x_mouse, y_mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                if x_mouse >= 600 and y_mouse >= 375:
                    game()


def mainScreen():
    background = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Images", "Background_00.png")).convert()
    FlappyDog = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Images", "Flappy.png")).convert_alpha()
    Play = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Images", "Play.png")).convert_alpha()
    Dog = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Images", "Dog0.png")).convert_alpha()
    SpikeUp0 = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Images", "SpikeUp0.png")).convert_alpha()
    SpikeUp1 = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Images", "SpikeUp1.png")).convert_alpha()
    SpikeDown0 = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Images", "SpikeDown0.png")).convert_alpha()
    SpikeDown1 = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Images", "SpikeDown1.png")).convert_alpha()
    Bone = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Images", "Bone.png")).convert_alpha()

    screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
    screen.blit(SpikeUp0, (0, 0))
    screen.blit(SpikeDown0, (0, 450))
    screen.blit(FlappyDog, (0, 0))
    screen.blit(Dog, (10, 250))
    screen.blit(Bone, (150, -300))
    screen.blit(Bone, (150, 400))
    screen.blit(Play, (650, 370))
    pygame.display.flip()

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
                pygame.display.update()
            if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                x_mouse, y_mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                if x_mouse >= 650 and y_mouse >= 370:
                    game()

mainScreen()
```

I don't know why, when I press the play button I go to the game screen for a second (I'm not touching the spikes) and I go to the game over screen.

There is no error message

Thanks in advantage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pygame.sprite.groupcollide` [returns a dictionary](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.groupcollide) that always includes the sprites in the first group. Therefore, the `if` test you have written will always return true.

You should re-write the function to check whether or not there are sprites in the list for every sprite in the `dog` group.

Comment: Ok, I understand. But how can I do a def or a if that returns me True or False?

Comment: @ArnauBG You should write a function that checks every list in the dictionary returned by groupcollide. If any of those lists has anything it it, return true. Otherwise, return false.

Comment: For the moment I have [This](https://gist.github.com/ArnauBG/6c173a8760e92a1ddf2b00c83564a6ce). It returns `{<Sprite sprite(in 1 groups)>: [<Sprite sprite(in 1 groups)>, <Sprite sprite(in 1 groups)>]}` @Joe What does it mean? Sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: @ArnauBG that's a dictionary with the results from groupcollide, with one entry. The first key is a Sprite, probably from dog. Its value is a list of two sprites, which are probably from spikes. I interpret that to mean, your dog has collided with at least two spikes.

Comment: No, in the game I press play, for a second I am on the game screen and passed a second I am at Game Over but returns me `{<Sprite sprite(in 1 groups)>: [<Sprite sprite(in 1 groups)>, <Sprite sprite(in 1 groups)>]}` everytime I press play.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the solution.

Change the way to make images sprites, like this:

```
Dog = pygame.sprite.Sprite()
Dog.rect = pygame.Rect(0, 100, 270, 256)
Bone = pygame.sprite.Sprite()
Bone.rect = pygame.Rect(850, 0, 87, 498)
Dog.image = pygame.image.load("Dog1.png").convert_alpha()
Bone.image = pygame.image.load("Bone.png").convert_alpha()
```

And don't use `pygame.sprite.groupcollide`, use `pygame.sprite.collide_rect(Dog, Bone)`

When blit the image replace the x and y pos. and use `Dog.rect.topleft` and `Bone.rect.topleft`. This will work.